# Kubernetes nginx ingress rabbitmq management and kibana

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rabbitmq, kibana, azure-aks

On my AKS cluster I have a Nginx ingress controller that I used to reverse proxy my kibana service running on the AKS. I want to however add another http services through the ingress, rabbitmq management console.

I'm unable to get both to work with the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-aegis
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /    
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.endpoint.net
    secretName: dev-secret   
  rules:
  - host: dev.endpoint.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-kibana
          servicePort: 5601
      - path: /rabbit
        backend:
          serviceName: rabbitmq
          servicePort: 15672
```

The Kibana works fine at root however RabbitMQ fails to load with a `503` with any path except `/`. If RabbitMQ's path is `/` then it works fine but then Kibana won't run.

I assume this is because internally they are sitting on the root aka localhost:15672 so it redirects to / on dev.endpoint.net.

How do I have multiple services like Kibana and RabbitmQ running from one endpoint?

Comment: Do you try to specialize the service port for the rabbitmq?

Comment: I missed that off the question. Now added.

Comment: Why creating only one ingress ? Why don't you create two different ingresses as it is two different domains and two different services ?

Comment: They are different services but are related under the same domain. Its easy enough to get multiple simple web applications working under multiple paths just not with more complex systems such as RabbitMQ and Kibana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is set the `basePath` for kibana to `/kibana`

See the below url

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

You are looking to configure `server.basePath` to `/kibana`. Then this will sort the reverse proxying issues and you can keep the MQ one directly on root `/`

You can also set `SERVER_BASEPATH` environment variable in your `kibana` pod and it will automatically pick the base path from that variable

Comment: Does that work with the official Kibana install from helm?

Comment: Can't confirm as I have not used helm, but I think it should work. Just try and let me know your feeback

Answer (score 2):

For RabbitMQ Management UI via ingress, set the following in the rabbitmq.conf file (you can use configmaps and mount the file inside the pod)

> management.path_prefix = /rabbit

In the Ingress set the following :

```
...
   path: /rabbit(/|$)(.*)
...
```

See : https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#path-prefix

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to fix my problem

Comment: Instead of mapping the config file, just add env:         
`RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS=-rabbitmq_management path_prefix "/rabbit"`

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to do host name based rules to switch backends. However, this would require a wildcard or SAN SSL certificate.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-aegis
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /    
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.endpoint.net
    - rabbit.endpoint.net
    secretName: dev-secret   
  rules:
  - host: dev.endpoint.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-kibana
          servicePort: 5601
  - host: rabbit.endpoint.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: rabbitmq
```

Comment: I'd like to keep it under the example of dev.endpoint.net and have the different resources as /resouce1 /resource2 etc

Comment: did you try this annotation, Service Upstream __ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"__
_The nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream annotation disables that behavior and instead uses a single upstream in NGINX, the service's Cluster IP and port_

Comment: Please take a look also for [Create an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls)
In this example they are using different annotations:`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` and  `path: /(.*)` and `path: /hello-world-two(/|$)(.*)`

Comment: No luck with either. Rabbitmq just returns a blank page with the resources loaded on the network but not displaying.

Comment: please take a loo for this [ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32709) on azure and rewrite issue. Please use curl -I -k for debugging your connection. Please verify also your chart and app version for nginx-ingress