# RabbitMQ management plugin: there is no template when using rewrite target from ingress nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rabbitmq, nginx-ingress

Kind of a weird one.

I have a cluster of RabbitMQ running on K8, using the [RabbitMQ Cluster Kubernetes Operator](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html). Nothing fancy for the Yaml config file. The name of the RabbitMQ service is **dev-rabbitmq**. The port 15672 (default) is to have access to the Management UI. Port forwarding works fine.

I have set-up a Ingress Nginx service to be able to customize the url in my browser. This, in order to have only one load balancer and have different URLs for different services
There are 2 scenarios, one which works (but not what I'm looking for). The other I get the below error message being displayed (and no option to login) only for Firefox.
[image: rabbitMQ_undefined_template]
I've tried using Firefox, Edge and Chrome

What works
**Ingress config**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rabbitmq 
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-dev
    app.kubernetes.io/component: reverse-proxy
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: helm
    niiwaa.com/environment: development
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  namespace: rabbits
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: dev-rabbitmq
            port: 
              number: 15672
    host: dev.hostname.com
```

Going to dev.hostname.com in my browser works as expected

If I change the path under spec.rules.http.paths.path to

```
path: /dev-rabbitmq
```

Then I get the error message in my browsers and no form to login.

I inspected the network console on both Edge and Firefox. On both cases, they send the request "GET [http://dev.hostname.com/js/ejs-1.0.min.js"](http://dev.hostname.com/js/ejs-1.0.min.js%22)
Only when my path is set to "/" that it is successful. Otherwise, I get a 404 error.

The reason is that the resource is at http://dev.hostname.com/dev-rabbitmq/js/ejs-1.0.min.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723867/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-rabbitmq-management-and-kibana) I was able to resolve it.

In my Yaml file for the RabbitMQ cluster, I added an additional config like so

```
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: dev-rabbitmq
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: rabbitmq-dev
    app.kubernetes.io/component: task-orchestrator
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: tasks
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: rabbitmqclusters
    niiwaa.com/environment: development
spec:
  rabbitmq:
    additionalConfig: |
      management.path_prefix = /dev-rabbitmq
```

And I removed the annotation *rewrite-target*

```
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
namespace: rabbits
```